# How to delete the row when comment is typed in Google web app?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm following a YouTube tutorial, I wrote the following script watching the video.

As you see in the screenshot, I want to **delete the row** when we type in the comment section as "***DELETE***" from the table. (The code is editable in the table itself and not in a form type)

Is there a way to do that?

[image]

**main.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.4.2/dist/css/tabulator_site.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
      .data-table {
      border: 1px solid #282828;
      background-color: #111111;
      }
      .data-table .tabulator-header {
      background-color: #080808;
      font-family: Arial;
      }

      .data-table .tabulator-row {
      background-color: #151515;
      font-family: Arial;
      }

      .data-table .tabulator-row.tabulator-row-even {
      background-color: #202020;
      }

      .data-table .tabulator-row.tabulator-selectable:hover {
      background-color: #000;
      }


      .data-table .tabulator-row .tabulator-cell {
      border-right-color: #393838;
      }

      .data-table .tabulator-row .tabulator-cell.tabulator-editing {
      border: 1px solid #3FB449;
      }

      .data-table .tabulator-row .tabulator-cell input,
      .data-table .tabulator-row .tabulator-cell select,
      .data-table .tabulator-row .tabulator-cell textarea {
      background-color: #121212;
      color: #ccc;
      }

      .data-table .tabulator-footer {
      background-color: #101010;
      }

      .data-table .tabulator-footer .tabulator-page,
      .data-table .tabulator-footer .tabulator-page-size {
      background: #ebebeb;
      }


      .data-table .tabulator-header .tabulator-col input,
      .data-table .tabulator-header .tabulator-col select {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 4px 10px;
      border: 1px solid #4b4b4b;
      border-radius: 2px;
      background: #1f1f1f;
      color: #fff;
      outline: none;
      }

      .data-table .tabulator-header .tabulator-col input:focus,
      .data-table .tabulator-header .tabulator-col select:focus {
      border-color: #3FB449;
      
      }

      .data-table .tabulator-header .tabulator-col input + input {
      margin-left: 5px;
      
      }

      .data-table .tabulator-header .tabulator-cell {
      color: #ccc !important;
      }

      .data-table .tabulator-tableholder .tabulator-table {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #E54522 ;
      }

    .search-box-outer, .add-record-box-outer{
      margin-bottom:1rem;

    }

  .search-box-inner, .add-record-box-inner{

    background-color: #111111;
    padding:0.5rem;
  }

  .search-box-inner input{
    color: #fff;
    padding:00.5rem;
    background-color: #393838;
    padding:00.5rem;
    border: 1px solid #3FB449;
    border-radius:00.2rem;

  }

  search-box-inner label{
    color: #fff;
    margin-righ:0.5rem;
    padding:0.5rem;
    
  }

  .add-record-box-inner button{
   color: #fff;
    padding:00.5rem;
    background-color: #393838;
    padding:00.5rem;
    border: 1px solid #3FB449;
    border-radius:00.2rem;
    cursor:pointer;
  }

  .row {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}
.block {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
    </style>

  </head>
<body>

   <div class="row">
      <div class ="search-box-outer">
        <div class ="search-box-inner">
           <div class ="add-record-box-outer">
        <div class ="add-record-box-inner">
        <label></label><input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search Task...">

     
        <button id="add-record">Add New Task</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    


  
    <div id="data-table" class="data-table"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="alerts"></div>
    

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/3.0.4/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-XdACFfCJeqqfVU8mvvXReyFR130qjFvfv/PZOFGwVyBz0HC+57fNkSacMPF2Dyek5jqi4D7ykFrx/T7N6F2hwQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.4.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

    <script src="luxon.js"></script>

    <script>




      const elements = {}
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",pageLoad)

      function pageLoad(){
        elements.alerts = document.getElementById("alerts")
        elements.search = document.getElementById("search")
        elements.addRecordButton = document.getElementById("add-record")
        
        
        elements.search.addEventListener("input",searchData)
        elements.addRecordButton.addEventListener("click",addRecord)
        loadData()
      }

      function loadData(){
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler((jsData) =>{
          //If data successfully returned

          
        //create Tabulator on DOM element with id "example-table"
          elements.table = new Tabulator("#data-table", {
             responsiveLayout:true,
            height:505, // set height of table (in CSS or here)
            data:jsData, //assign data to table
            layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
              pagination:true,
              paginationSize:10,
            columns:[ //Define Table Columns
              {title:"ID", field:"ID",width:100},
              {title:"Task", field:"Task", editor:"input"},
              {title:"Assigned", field:"Assigned", editor:"list", editorParams:{values:["Aadhil", "Asram","Aariff","Hasitha","Proboth"]}},
              {title:"Status", field:"Status",editor:"list", editorParams:{values:["Important", "Not Urgent","This Week","Today","Urgent"]}},
              {title:"Comments", field:"Comments",editor:"input"},
              {title:"Task Progress", field:"Progress",  hozAlign:"left", formatter:"progress", editor:true},
              {title:"Complete", field:"Complete",  hozAlign:"center",width:120, formatter:"tickCross",formatterParams:{crossElement: false}, sorter:"boolean", editor:true},
            ],
          })

      

          elements.table.on("cellEdited", function(cell){
                //cell - cell component

                const id = cell._cell.row.data.ID
                
                const field = cell._cell.column.field
                const type = cell._cell.column.definition.formatter

                const val = type === "tickCross"? Number(cell._cell.value) : cell._cell.value
                console.log(cell._cell)
                if (["Assigned","Task","Comments","Status","Complete","Progress"].includes(field)){
                  elements.alerts.textContent = "Saving Changes..."
                    google.script.run
                    .withSuccessHandler(()=>{
                      elements.alerts.textContent = "SAVED!"
                      clearAlerts(elements.alerts)
                    })
                    .withFailureHandler((er)=>{
                      elements.alerts.textContent = "ERROR Saving Changes"            
                    clearAlerts(elements.alerts)
                    })                   
                    .editCell({id: id, val: val, field: field})

                }


          });

          //end if data successfully returned
        })
        .withFailureHandler((er) => {

        })
        .getData()
      }



    function clearAlerts(el){
      setTimeout(() => {
        el.textContent = ""

      },2500)
    }

function searchData(e){
 elements.table.setFilter("Task", "like", e.target.value);
}

function addRecord(){
google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler((newId)=>{
elements.table.addRow({ID:newId}, true)

})
.withFailureHandler((er)=>{
  console.log("Error adding the new record")

})                   
.addRecord()

}



    </script>
  </body>
    </html>
```

**dataServerSide.gs**

```
 function getData() {
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
 const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data")
 const dataRange = ws.getRange("A1").getDataRegion()
 const data = dataRange.getDisplayValues()

 const headers = data.shift()

//  console.log(headers)
//  console.log(data)

 const jsData = data.map(r => {
   const tempObject = {}
  headers.forEach((header,i) => {
    tempObject[header] = r[i]
  })
  return tempObject
 })
 console.log(jsData)
return jsData
}//end of get Data function

function editCell(props){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data")
  const idCellMatched = ws.getRange("A2:A").createTextFinder(props.id).matchEntireCell(true).matchCase(true).findNext()

  const columnCellMatched = ws.getRange("1:1").createTextFinder(props.field).matchEntireCell(true).matchCase(true).findNext()

  if(idCellMatched === null) throw new Error("No Matching Record")
  if(columnCellMatched === null) throw new Error("Invalid Field")

  const recordRowNumber = idCellMatched.getRow()
  const recordColumnNumber = columnCellMatched.getColumn()


  ws.getRange(recordRowNumber,recordColumnNumber).setValue(props.val)
}


function addRecord(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data")
   
  const newId = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5:30", "dd-MMM-yyyy|hh:mm:ss")
  Logger.log(newId)
  ws.appendRow([newId])
  return newId
}
```

Comment: I'm worried that your `main.html` is incomplete. Can you provide the script for replicating your current situation?

Comment: @Tanaike I've update the main.html with all scripts in it.

Comment: You can make a copy of this sheet if you require more details https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bXYqjm2vMPdM2IJUPWgPTePuVbQl9ZN6SOHvUwB7Snc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to delete a row when `DELETE` is put to the column "Comments" in the table.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
elements.table.on("cellEdited", function(cell){
```

#### To:

```
elements.table.on("cellEdited", function(cell){

  // I added the below script.
  if (cell.getValue().toUpperCase() == "DELETE") {
    cell.getRow().delete();
  }
```

or, if you want to also check the column, please use the following modification.

```
elements.table.on("cellEdited", function(cell){

  // I added the below script.
  if (cell.getValue().toUpperCase() == "DELETE" && cell.getColumn().getDefinition().title == "Comments") {
    cell.getRow().delete();
  }
```

- When this script is run, when the cell of column "Comments" is edited to "DELETE", the row is deleted.

#### Reference:

- [Tabulator](https://tabulator.info/)

### Added:

From `I want to delete the row from the front end table and as well as in the Google sheet table (backend)`, in this case, please modify `editCell(props)` of Google Apps Script as follows.

#### From:

```
ws.getRange(recordRowNumber,recordColumnNumber).setValue(props.val)
```

#### To:

```
if (props.val.toUpperCase() == "DELETE") {
  ws.deleteRow(recordRowNumber);
} else {
  ws.getRange(recordRowNumber, recordColumnNumber).setValue(props.val);
}
```

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

Comment: Sorry. In this case, it is no 2nd argument.

Comment: The front end row is getting deleted but it's not getting deleted in the Google sheet. When we refresh, the table is back with old entries.

Comment: @Miyer Thank you for replying. About `but it's not getting deleted in the Google sheet. When we refresh, the table is back with old entries.`, it's yes. From your question of `I want to delete the row when we type in the comment section as "DELETE" from the table.`, I thought that you wanted to remove the row in the table. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is not correct, I have to apologize.

Comment: Well.. Sorry for the confusion, I want to delete the row from the front end table and as well as in the Google sheet table (backend)

Comment: @Miyer Thank you for replying. About `I want to delete the row from the front end table and as well as in the Google sheet table (backend)`, I added one more modification point in my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Thank you very much :) It took for me so many hours with test and trial. finally you helped me. THANK YOU :)

Comment: @Miyer Thank you for replying and testing it, again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: For some reason the "Progress" bar (F column) and the "Complete" tick (G column) isn't updating the Google sheets. but the remaining (A,B,C,D,E) columns are working. Can you please help to fix this, I don't understand where it went wrong.

Comment: @Miyer About your new issue of `For some reason the "Progress" bar (F column) and the "Complete" tick (G column) isn't updating the Google sheets. but the remaining (A,B,C,D,E) columns are working. Can you please help to fix this, I don't understand where it went wrong.`, I would like to support you. In this case, can you post it as a new question? By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. When you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: I've added a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74148509/the-columns-arent-getting-updated-in-google-sheets